# Публикация приложения asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, публикация-приложений

Пытаюсь опубликовать ASP.NET Core приложение на бесплатном хостинге freeasphosting.net, но ничего не получается, просто выдаёт ошибку 500, когда захожу на свой сайт. Публиковал через Visual Studio проект - Publish - в локальную папку, а дальше уже загружал на хостинг. Что нужно сделать, чтобы приложение заработало? Может, дело в конфигурации? Спасибо.

Comment: Смотрите логи. Если у вас нет логирования, сделайте его.

Comment: Да я даже логи посмотреть не могу, сам хостинг выдаёт 500 ошибку

Comment: Может быть,  я в принципе не так публикую, не ту папку туда кладу?

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть конкретный текст 500-ой ошибки, например в хроме: F12 -> Сеть (Network) -> клик по запросу с 500